# $f(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+p=0$ has no integral solutions.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

let $p$ be a prime number, does the polynomial:$f(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+p=0$ have any integral solution if $p>a>2$ and $ x>2 $?

I concluded that there was none on the basis that $p>a$ and a prime. Is my reasoning flawed?

Comment: I don't know if your reasoning is flawed, but it's certainly incomplete and non-obvious that that's sufficient...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $b$ is a free variable you're asking if $x^3+ax^2+p$ can be a multiple of $x$. Sure, $x = p$.

It's probably easy to name a case where there isn't an integral solution as well. So your conditions do not imply whether there is an integral solution, either way.

Comment: But x=p is not a solution of the polynomial unless x=p=0. Isn't it? which is absurd, since 0 is not a prime number. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @NumThcurious it is if $b$ is $(-p^3-ap^2-p)/p$ even if $p$ is 641 or 1009 or whatever.